# A List<Tuple<int, float>> in managed C++

Tags: c#, c++, list, tuples, managed

I'm working on some software that is written in native C++ with a managed C++ wrapper and the user interface in C#.  I need to pass some information from the native code all the way up to the interface.  The best way I can think to pass my information is in a list of tuples.  I understand that in the native C++ I need to use a `list<tuple<..>>` and that works fine.  What I want to do now, is take that output in the wrapper, and return a `List<Tuple<..>>` which is the `System::Collections::Generic::List` and `System::Tuple` instead of the stl ones from the native.  I know the lists are very different syntactically but that shouldn't be the issue.  In the C# code a `List<Tuple<..>>` is accepted by the compiler but in the managed C++ code it is not.  Am I doing this wrong/am I using the wrong data types? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI or something?

Comment: yeah that's the managed c++ wrapper

Comment: Have you got the correct namespaces being used and projects referenced? What's the exact message the compiler gives?

Comment: The namespaces were good and the compiler just said that Tuple is not a valid generic argument...I just changed it to List<Tuple<int, float>^>^ and it was ok....I had someone else try in a little test project to do it the way I was doing it and they had no problems so I'm still not sure what is going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

// A List<Tuple<int, float>> in managed C++
public ref class TupleTest
{
public:
    static List<Tuple<int, float>^>^ GetTuple() {
        List<Tuple<int, float>^>^ ret = gcnew List<Tuple<int,float>^>();
        Tuple<int,float>^ t = gcnew Tuple<int,float>(5, 2.6);
        ret->Add(t);
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Note: you could use Int32 and Single (or Double) instead of int/float if you like.

**EDIT:** Notice the `^` operators.  Those denote C++/CLI reference types.  You'll be using them a lot! (It's kinda like `*` for pointers in regular C++, but means GC'ed reference type)

Comment: Ok so I needed the two ^'s .... I tried using them before but it wasn't working all that well....managed C++ gives me headaches

Comment: @IanPanzica Remember to call it C++/CLI, at least on Stack Overflow.  Managed C++ will confuse folks who used the older .Net C++ implementations as well.

Comment: I will remember that thanks! My boss just calls it managed C++ so that's what sticks in my head.

Comment: @IanPanzica Mine too!